# Ionic 3 toolbar button won't change from outline to solid

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to change a button on the toolbar in Ionic 3 from Outline to Solid dynamically but I'm not able to.

My HTML code is the following:

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button 
    [outline]="testButtonOutline" 
    [color]="testButtonColor" 
    [solid]="testButtonSolid" 
    (click)="testMode()">
      {{testModeLabel}}
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title left>Choose alert</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

My .TS function is:

```
testMode() {
  if (this.testModeState == false) {
    this.testModeLabel = 'Test Mode: On';
    this.testModeState = true;
    this.testButtonColor = 'primary';
    this.testButtonOutline = false;
    this.testButtonSolid = true;
  }
  else {
    this.testModeLabel = 'Test Mode: Off';
    this.testModeState = false;
    this.testButtonColor = 'Grey';
    this.testButtonOutline = true;
    this.testButtonSolid = false;
  }
}
```

it seems that [outline] gets overridden when I introduce the [solid]="testButtonSolid" option even if [solid] is set to false.

Comment: Can you simulate it here:https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I'm getting the same issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jaftwz

Comment: It toggles nicely no? What is the issue?

Comment: It toggles to [solid] nicely but it never toggles to [outline]. I want to make it look like there is a button there when it's not in [solid]. If you remove the [solid] component, the outline shows up but then it doesn't look like a button when it's not it [outline].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the outer `<ion-buttons end>` button. You need to remove it.If you have any issue to align the buttons then you can use the [**ionic grid**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/).And you don't need to give the `solid` since it is the `default`.

```
<button ion-button [outline]="testButtonOutline" [color]="testButtonColor" (click)="testMode()">
        {{testModeLabel}}
</button>
```

Working [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qqbsiu?file=pages/home/home.ts)